# dictionary is empty when called from another class

Tags: c#, class, dictionary

i have this 2 classes inside 1 file

this **Character**

```
public class Character{
    public static int Count = 0;
    public string username, charname;
    public int gender, level, money, playtime;

    public Character(string _username, string _charname, int _gender, int _level, int _money, int _playtime)
    {
        username = _username;
        charname = _charname;
        gender = _gender;
        level = _level;
        money = _money;
        playtime = _playtime;
        Count++;
    }
}
```

and this **Player**

```
public class Player : Script
{
    public Dictionary<string, Character> CharacterList = new Dictionary<string, Character>();
}
```

and i wanted to call **CharacterList** Dictionary from another class in another file like this

```
public class AmmuNation : Script
{
    Player Ply = new Player();

    public void Test(Client sender)
    {
        API.consoleOutput(Ply.CharacterList[sender.name].charname);
    }
}
```

but when the **Test()** executed it gives me this error even though the Key is in the dictionary

> The given key was not present in the dictionary.
>
> at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)

it worked when i call it from the class **Player** and will give me the value of charname

but when i call it from **AmmuNation** it will say that the Key is not found

even the Dictionary is empty when i tried this

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Character> kvp in Ply.CharacterList)
{
    API.consoleOutput(kvp.Key);
}
```

but on **Player** it will print every Key inside the **CharacterList**

Comment: You're making a new `Player` object in `AmmuNation` and that object gets its own Dictionary. If you want to use the same Dictionary in both places, you need to use the same `Player` object in both places. Or make `CharacterList` static. Something.

Comment: @itsme86 when i make the CharacterList static it says cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead
what does that mean, i'm new with OOP stuff sorry

Comment: How are you populating the dictionary in class `Player`? How are you calling it from the class `Player`? What is the role of parameter `Client sender` passed in `Player` constructor?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya

i'm adding the dictionary in class Player using Add(), 

i'm calling it directly because it's property of the class Player, 

"Client sender" is just another class that contain variable "name" so i can get the dictionary Key using "sender.name"

Comment: The dictionary population code gets executed also before you try to access the dictionary in the test method? Can you share the code of dictionary population and how are using it in player and AmmuNation class test method?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya nevermind sir i got the solution after watching some youtube videos, all i need to do is setting the Dictionary to static and calling it using directly the class name like this "Player.CharacterList"

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya oh and sorry about the typo the "Client sender" was supposed to go inside Test method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution after watching some youtube video
all i need to do is setting the CharacterList Dictionary to static and then calling it from AmmuNation using the class name like this

```
public class AmmuNation : Script
{
    public void Test()
    {
        API.consoleOutput(Player.CharacterList[sender.name].charname);
    }
}
```

also i don't need the

```
Player Ply = new Player();
```

anymore